# Calling UIWebView from IBAction ButtonPressed

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

This is probably a simple question...

I have a UIView with a button that corresponds to a URL address http:// etc. I want to be able to click this web address button and have it load a UIWebView on a separate `UIViewController` and XIB that shows the website, allowing me to then hit a back button and go back to my first view that has the original button. Basically I want to be able to load the webpage but have it operate within the App rather than start up Safari. Is this possible?

So far I have build a dedicated XIB and ViewController for my webpage for which the `viewDidLoad` method looks like this:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad{  
  [super viewDidLoad];  
NSString *urlAddress = pushURL; //pushURL is passed as parameter 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:requestObject];  
[addressBar setText:urlAddress];
 }
```

Question is... how do I call the UIWebView from my button (which is in the first class/parent viewController)? All my other `viewControllers` in my app are using UITableView so it's a simple `DidSelectRowAtIndex`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be using a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Then when the button is tapped just push the UIViewController with the web view to the UINavigationController.